# unable to upload file from my react application

Tags: reactjs

I want to need upload file from react application to backend.

my upload handle function is:

```
 handleupload(info) {
  this.setState({ 'selectedFiles': info.fileList });
}
```

But we are unable to send file data to server.

we are using axios:

```
 export async function saveApplication(applicationData) {
  return http.post(
    getJobsEndPoint+"/store-application",
    applicationData, 
    {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    }
  );
}
```

But stil unable to get request on my backend controller, we are getting all input type in my backend controller. But still unable to find file object.

Please help me any buddy for regarding same.

Comment: Where does handleUpload get `info` from?

Comment: Also, where do you call `saveApplication`?

Comment: Since you provide less relevant information, reading this section (https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag) in the react docs might help you fix the issue